PHP openssl_decrypt Occasionally Returns Unexpected Value Instead of False
I am trying to rotate our encryption keys and encountered the following problem - I expected openssl_decrypt() to always return false when when using an invalid encryption key, but it occasionally returns an unexpected value instead. I need to keep both the old and new keys active for about 30 days.
How to replicate:
// KEY_1 is the old key and KEY_2 is the new key
define('KEY_1', 'v3pQz7gtWaGF8N62EFK3VUv0m233ATde3c77z6oC5dk='); // openssl rand -base64 32
define('KEY_2', 'YDqviTmcH1iQJ1KdZXnOD8JILeqOV18t4T2t029Zp3s=');

$testString = '1996'; // or '1252', '1963'
$iv = 'kMg6JRRCq/jPcIQWzE+44Q==';

$encryptedValueUsingKey1 = openssl_encrypt($testString, 'aes128', KEY_1, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, base64_decode($iv));

// try decrypting using new key
$decryptedValue = openssl_decrypt($encryptedValueUsingKey1, 'aes128', KEY_2, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, base64_decode($iv)); // expected to be false, but has a value

// fallback to KEY_1 - but never run because $decryptedValue has value: ��e�hf2e��8�@�&
if (!$decryptedValue) {
    $decryptedValue = openssl_decrypt($encryptedValueUsingKey1, 'aes128', KEY_1, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, base64_decode($iv));
}

print_r($decryptedValue); // expected '1996'

Why doesn't openssl_decrypt() always return false when an incorrect encryption key is used? I want to be able to rotate encryption keys, with both keys being active for a short time, but cannot do so if I cannot guarantee that openssl_decrypt() will return false. How can I have both keys active for a time while I perform the rotation?
Other Notes:

I just generated an example range of numbers from 1 - 9999 for this example. The vast majority of the time, I got the expected false from openssl_decrypt(). This is just one example of where my fallback does not work.
The initialization vector is constant for all encrypted values in this system. It was generated using this code:

Code for generating IV:
$ivLen = openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes128');
$ivEnc = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivLen);
$iv = base64_encode($iv);


The CBC mode (which is the default one) was not designed to detect an incorrect key. In such a case, it generally fails because the padding is invalid, but sometimes the padding happens to be valid and openssl_decrypt() will return a result.

By the way, you are supposed to pass the key in a binary form, not Base64.

There is slightly more than a 1/256 chance that decrypting with an invalid key will not be detected, due to the nature of the PKCS7 padding being used.

Authenticated encryption may be an option, e.g. GCM, which is supported by PHP/OpenSSL. If the key is wrong, authentication fails (returning false).

Store a bit of metadata with the ciphertext that indicates which key version was used.
